# How to use the bitcoin client without downloading the blockchain?

Tags: bitcoind

I would like to be able to use the bitcoin python client to be able to do things like sign transactions offline, create transactions, create multisig transactions, etc.

Is there a way to do this without having to download the whole bitcoin blockchain 20 GB?

I don't mind looking up the bitcoin addresses, outputs and such using an external website (e.g., blockchain.org) using some sort of API.

Is the a client that does this?

Answer (score 1):

[Electrum](https://electrum.org/) is an SPV wallet which has most of the functionality you mentioned.

Multisig is an issue though, the primary solution I'm aware of at this time is hybrid wallets such as [Copay](https://copay.io/).

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this programmatically would be to use [Bitcore](http://bitcore.io/). It interfaces with a "blockchain explorer" to obtain stuff like outputs and addresses, and they can either be installed locally or you can use one from the ones already online: https://insight.is/ - and they're all open-source coming from the BitPay people.